# are mg996r servo failures common?

Tags: servomotor, pwm

I am new to the small servo area.

I bought a eBay 6DOF Robotic Arm, and 12 mg996r servos to go with it.

Using an arduino and I2C PCA9685 16 X PWM board, with the example code from adafruit, I set up 5 of the servos with conservative values for an overnight test.

2 of the servos died, and individually, zero response from voltage applied to them (no hum, no increase or decrease in mechanical moving, no heat).

Since then, I've had another one die.

Is this common on buying "bottom feeder" prices on ebay?

I was wanting to get into this area without spending a bundle, but 25% failure rates seems excessive even for ebay.

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: like they say "you get what you pay for" .... please post your test code .... maybe there is an error in the code that causes the servo to crash

Answer (score -1):

You must drive servos at 25hz or you'll fry them. I ran mine at 300hz until they melted internally.